# MultiStage Pipeline triggers from more than one branch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I have a pipeline in Azure DevOps that is triggering from more than just the branch I have specified in the yaml file. I am using bitbucket cloud for my repository.

At first I had the trigger set like this:

```
trigger:
- development
```

Then I changed it to this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - development
```

It is still triggering from 2 other branches besides development. When I look at the branches tab on the pipeline it has development and the other 2 branches it's triggering from. I also don't have any triggers set in the UI.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Post your entire pipeline. Are you using Bitbucket as your repo hosting platform? The question is tagged with Bitbucket but you don't explicitly state that anywhere.

Comment: @DanielMann I mentioned bitbucket cloud in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the YAML file in the correct branch? The branch the pipeline definition is derived from?

As a workaround you could try to add the excludes clause in your YAML trigger to ignore those other two branches.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - development
    exclude:
    - PBI123
    - PBI456
```

A note on the Branches tab, this is a summary of the pipeline runs that have already been executed, it is not a listing of the branches what will be executed by the pipeline.

I hope this helps resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes I have it in the development branch. But it seems to be adding new branches anytime a PR is made on development. 

I added this 

`trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - development
pr: none`

Doesn't seem to solve it though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after looking into it some more I believe this solves it:

```
pr: none
```

As long as the PR has that in it. It shouldn't trigger.